# generate autocomplete using soap and jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, parsing, soap

i need to generate a autocomplete using soap web service.

My soap request is

```
POST /REMEDIFINDERSERVICES/HSWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.24
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.healthsprint.com/GetInsuranceXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetInsuranceXML xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com">
  <HospCode>string</HospCode>
</GetInsuranceXML>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <GetInsuranceXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com">
  <GetInsuranceXMLResult>string</GetInsuranceXMLResult>
  </GetInsuranceXMLResponse>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

i used jquery in this way

```
var insArr = [];

var insuranceRequest =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<GetInsuranceXML xmlns="http://www.healthsprint.com"> \
  <HospCode>' + $(".provider").val() + '</HospCode> \
</GetSpecialityXML> \
</soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
  url: "http://192.168.1.24/REMEDIFINDERSERVICES/HSWebService.asmx?op=GetInsuranceXML", 
  dataType: "xml",
  data:insuranceRequest,
  success: parsNxml,
  complete: setupNewac,
  failure: function(data) {
  alert("XML File could not be found");
  }

  });

  function parsNxml(data, xml)
 {
 //find every query value
 $(xml).find("GetInsuranceXMLResult").each(function()
 {
 insArr.push($(this).text());
 });
 }

 function setupNewac() {
 $("input.provider").autocomplete({
 source: insArr,
 minLength: 1,
 select: function(event, ui) {
 $("input.provider").val(ui.item.value);
 }
 });
 }
```

but this does code is not working i'm not getting any data. what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run firebug or similar inspector and check what ajax call returns.

Comment: is it a cross domain request.. whether your page is loaded from the same domain as `http://192.168.1.24/`

Comment: yes my page is loading from the same domain

Comment: looks like it should be `$(data).find("GetInsuranceXMLResult").each(function()`